# Are repeated properties equivalent to array properties?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

From the [Cloud Datastore section of Migrating Services from the Standard Environment to the Flexible Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/migrating#datastore):

> The same Cloud Datastore data is available regardless of if you use
>   the App Engine libraries, the Google Cloud client libraries, or call
>   the API directly.

In the context of the same entity does a **repeated** property from an App Engine library (like [python ndb client library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entity-property-reference#repeated) or [Java Datastore API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities#Java_Repeated_properties) for example) correspond to an [**array** property from the Google Cloud Datastore API](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#array)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, these are equivalent concepts.